# Power shell and .bat file

Tags: powershell

Because im not so good in power shell, i wanted to ask how to manage this task. I have created .bat file which doing this:

```
echo before delete > delete.log

forfiles -p "C:\test1" -s -m *.* -d -0 -c "cmd /c echo @path" >> trace.log

forfiles -p "C:\test1" -s -m *.* -d -1 -c "cmd /c del @path" >> trace.log

echo preserved  >> trace.log

forfiles -p "C:\test1" -s -m *.* -d -0 -c "cmd /c echo @path" >> trace.log
```

And output of that trace.log i send successfully via separate power shell script like this:

```
$body = Get-Content -Path "C:\test1\trace.log" -Raw
Send-MailMessage -from doNotReply@company.com -to "nobody@company.com" -subject "Trace log delete status test" -body $body -smtpServer smtp.company.com
```

Because of my limited knowledge in power shell is there a way to merge .bat commands with my current power shell script? Idea is to do action of delete like in above sample, create log and send it by email in one power shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Write-Host "before delete" > delete.log
(Get-ChildItem "C:\test1" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >>trace.log
(Get-ChildItem "C:\test1" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} |
    Remove-Item -Force) >>trace.log
Write-Host "preserved"  >> trace.log
(Get-ChildItem "C:\test1" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >>trace.log
$body = Get-Content -Path "C:\test1\trace.log" -Raw
Send-MailMessage -from doNotReply@company.com -to "nobody@company.com" -subject "Trace log delete status test" -body $body -smtpServer smtp.company.com
```

Comment: Now i hit this error .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. I tried with several combinations of Set-ExecutionPolicy but i failed, any suggestions?

Comment: @user3391373 You should be more precise. *what* exactly have you tried and *how* did it fail. Also, there are lots of posts on stackoverflow addressing that problem.

Answer (score 0):

@marsze Ok sorry, so i run ISE like admin user and executed this line *Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine Unrestricted*. Than i copied all above proposed code in same session and run, and i hit this errors:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Websense\Websense Endpoint\certutil' is denied.
At line:8 char:2
+ (Get-ChildItem "C:\test1" -Recurse |
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...dpoint\certutil:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauth 
   orizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CCM\ScriptStore' is denied.
At line:8 char:2
+ (Get-ChildItem "C:\test1" -Recurse |
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CCM\ScriptStore:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedA 
   ccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```